# Should I delete listeners on pre/post save/remove in mongoose?

Tags: node.js, mongoose, socket.io

I register new post save listener with Schema.post('save', function) every time when socket connects. Should I delete listener when socket disconnects to avoid memory leaks? If yes how to do it?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? Schema hooks should be registered just once.

Comment: @robertklep So register new hook for every socket is bad, right?